# SQL LEFT JOIN is not filling a column with values from table 2

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT zmogaus_id, hobio_id, hobio_pav2
FROM zmogaus_hobiai 
LEFT JOIN hobiai 
ON zmogaus_hobiai.hobio_pav2=hobiai.hobio_pav
WHERE zmogaus_id=3
```

Using this I want to get

```
zomgaus_id =3 . hobio_id =1 . hobio_pav2 =name1 (from hobio_pav)
zomgaus_id =3 . hobio_id =2 . hobio_pav2 =name2 (from hobio_pav)
```

But hobio_pav2 stays as an empty column. I tried not having hobio_pav2 column but the problem persists of not adding hobio_pav values to corresponding IDs to hobio_id.
hobio_pav2 column is empty

EDIT:

sample data:

```
table hobiai: id = 1, hobio_pav = name1;id = 2, hobio_pav = name2;id = 3, hobio_pav = name3;

    table zmogaus_hobiai: 
id =1, zmogaus_id=2, hobio_id=2, hobio_pav2 = null;
id =2, zmogaus_id=2, hobio_id=3, hobio_pav2 = null;
id =4, zmogaus_id=3, hobio_id=1, hobio_pav2 = null;
id =5, zmogaus_id=3, hobio_id=3, hobio_pav2 = null;
```

Desired result:

```
generated table: 
zmogaus_id=3, hobio_id=1, hobio_pav2=name1;
zmogaus_id=3, hobio_id=3, hobio_pav2=name3;
```

Got result:

```
generated table: 
zmogaus_id=3, hobio_id=1, hobio_pav2= ;
zmogaus_id=3, hobio_id=3, hobio_pav2= ;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results, please.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update

zmogaus_hobiai

```
UPDATE zmogaus_hobiai zh INNER JOIN hobiai h
    ON zh.hobio_id=h.id
    SET zh.hobio_pav2 = h.hobio_pav
    WHERE zmogaus_id=3;
```

And your SELECT would look like this

```
SELECT zmogaus_id, h.hobio_id, hobio_pav
FROM zmogaus_hobiai  zh
INNER JOIN hobiai h
ON zh.hobio_id=h.id
WHERE zmogaus_id=3:
```

Comment: I did not want to update the table, I wanted to filter just those hobio_id that have the same zmogaus_id also, and then use that hobio_id and hobio_pav to do some stuff in php, i thought it will be easyer if i just used left join, but now i think i should just give not just hobio_id to zmogaus_hobiai but also hobio_pav.
Sorry im rambling, you gave me an easier solution than waht i was looking for haha

Comment: no in your case is better to use INNEr JOIN and you will se my SELECT query will give you the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `coalesce()`?

```
SELECT zh.zmogaus_id, coalesce(h.hobio_id, zh.hobio_pav2)
FROM zmogaus_hobiai zh LEFT JOIN
     hobiai h
     ON zh.hobio_pav2 = h.hobio_pav
WHERE zh.zmogaus_id = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

From your sample data, it looks like you just need to fix your join condition - you should be joining on `id`s rather than on those other string columns:

```
SELECT z.zmogaus_id, z.hobio_id, h.hobio_pav2
FROM zmogaus_hobiai z
LEFT JOIN hobiai h ON h.id = z.zmogaus_id
WHERE z.zmogaus_id = 3
```

Note that I added table aliases and prefixed all columns with the table they belong to. This makes the query easier to read, and avoids ambiguity when different tables have homonym columns.